# RESTful API HATEOAS

Tags: api, rest, hateoas

I've come to the conclusion that building a truly RESTful API, one the uses HATEOAS is next to impossible.

Every content I've come across either fails to illustrate the true power of HATEOAS
or simply does not explicitly mentions the inherent pain points with the dynamic nature of HATEOAS.

### What I believe HATEOAS is all about:

From my understanding, a truly HATEOAS API should have ALL the information needed to interact with the API, and while that is possible, it is a nightmare to use, especially with different stacks.

For example, consider a collection of resources located at "/books":

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
        "self": "/book/sdgr345",
        "id": "sdgr345",
        "name": "Building a RESTful API - The unspoken truth",
        "author": "Elad Chen ;)",
        "published": 1607606637049000
    }
  ],

  // This describes every field needed to create a new book
  // just like HyperText Markup Language (i.e. HTML) rendered on the server does with forms
  "create-form": {
    "href": "/books",
    "method": "POST",
    "rel": ["create-form"],
    "accept": ["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
    "fields": [
        { "name": "name", "label": "Name", "type": "text", "max-length": "255", "required": true }
        { "name": "author", "label": "Author", "type": "text", "max-length": "255", "required": true }
        { "name": "author", "label": "Publish Date", "type": "date", "format": "dd/mm/YY", "required": true }
    ]
  }
}
```

Giving the above response, a client (such as a web app) can use the "create-form" property to render an actual HTML form.

What value do we get from all this work?

**The same value we've been getting from HTML for years.**

Think about it, this is exactly what hypertext is all about, and what HTML has been designed for.

When a browser hits "www.pizza.com" the browser has no knowledge of the other paths that a user
can visit, it does not concatenate strings to produce a link to the order page -> "www.pizza.com/order", it simply renders anchors
and navigates when a user clicks them. This is what allows web developers to change the path from "/order" to "/shut-up-and-take-my-money" without changing any client (browsers).

The above idea is also true for forms, browsers do not guess the parameters needed to order a pizza, they simply render a form and its inputs, and handle its submission.

I have seen too many lines of codes in front-ends and back-ends alike, that build strings
like -> "https://api.com" + "/order" - **You don't see browsers do that, right?**

### The problems with HATEOAS

Giving the above example ("/books" response), in order to create a new book, clients are expected to parse the response in order to leverage the true power of this RESTful API, otherwise, they risk assuming what the names of the fields are, which of them is required, what their expected type is, etc...

Now consider having two clients within your company that are using this API,
one for the web (browsers) written in JS, and another for the mobile (say an android app) written in Java. They can be published as SDK's, hopefully making 3 party consumers have an easier integration.

As soon as the API is used by clients outside your control, say a 3rd party developer with an affinity to python, with the purpose of creating a new book.
That developer is REQUIRED to parse such a response, to figure out what the parameters are, their name, the URL to send inputs to, and so on.

In all my years of developing I have yet to come across an API such as the one I have in mind.
I have a feeling this type of API is nothing more than a pipe dream, and I was hoping to understand whether my assumptions are correct, and what downfalls it brings before starting the implementation phase.

P.S
in case it's not clear, this is exactly what HATEOAS compliant API is all about - when the fields to create a book change clients adapt without breaking.

Comment: So what is your question exactly? If there are hypermedia driven APIs out there? If you should write one? If your understanding of HATEOAS is correct? Something else entirely?!?

Comment: If there are hypermedia driven APIs out there.

Whether changing a resource URI is risky given I don't believe clients actually "navigate" the API

Comment: This is a rant, not a question.

Comment: (A well-reasoned rant, mind you.)

Comment: But it did end with a question :)

Comment: Jeff Doolittle makes an argument (almost) that the only true HATEOAS is HTML...I disagree with him but the talk addresses many points of your rant. [REST,Wrecks,Microservices](https://youtu.be/q1n_0kw5uBc)

Comment: @mdisibio The video looks promising, but there is no audio at a certain point. Any other source?

Comment: Yes that was a link with known audio issues. Try this one: [REST, Wrecks, Microservices](https://youtu.be/XTUIj-YqVzs)

Comment: Code on demand could help you. You can tell the client a link where there can get some code to handle the form, for example.

Comment: Agree. It was someone thesis or something that got put on the web and now everyone thinks it's a standard. I've had colleagues pollute client API specs with it, and partners add this to their responses. Not all bandwagons need to be jumped on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing a HATEOAS API needs to be done both on the server and on the clients, so this point you make in the comments is very valid indeed:

> changing a resource URI is risky given I don't believe clients actually "navigate" the API

Besides the World Wide Web, which is the best implementation of HATEOAS, I only know of [the SunCloud API on the now decommissioned Project Kenai](http://web.archive.org/web/20170409025922/https://kenai.com/projects/suncloudapis/pages/Home). Most APIs out there don't quite make use of HATEOAS, but are just a bunch of documented URLs where you can get or submit specific resources (basically, instead of being "hypermedia driven", they are "documentation driven"). With this type of API, clients don't actually navigate the API, they concatenate strings to go at specific endpoints where they know they can find specific resources.

If you expose a HATEOAS API, developers of any clients can still look at the links you return and may decide to build them on their own 'cause they figure what the API is doing, so then think they can just bypass any other navigation that might be needed and go straight for the URL, because it is always `/products/categories/123`, until - of course - it isn't anymore.

A HATEOAS API is more difficult to build and adds complexity to both the server and the clients, so when deciding to build one, the questions are:

- do you need the flexibility HATEOAS is giving you to justify the extra complexity of the implementation?
- do you want to make it easier or harder for clients to consume your API?
- does the knowledge and discipline to make it all work exist on both sides (server developers and clients developers)?

Most of the times, the answer is no. In addition, many times the questions don't even get asked, instead people end up with the approach that is more familiar because they've seen the sort of APIs people build, have used some, or built some before. Also, many times, a REST API is just stuck in front of a database and doesn't do much but expose data from the database as JSON or XML, so not that much need for navigation there.

There is no one forcing you to implement HATEOAS in your API, and no one preventing you to do so either. At the end of the day, it's a matter of deciding if you want to expose your API this way or not (another example would be, do you expose your resources as JSON, XML, or let the client chose the content type?).

In the end, there is always the chance of breaking your clients when you make changes to your API (HATEOAS or no HATEOAS), because you don't control your clients and you can't control how knowledgeable the client developer are, how disciplined, or how good of a work they do in implementing someone else's API.

Answer (score 10):

On the [Hypermedia Maturity Model](https://8thlight.com/blog/jason-desrosiers/2018/05/30/the-hypermedia-maturity-model.html) (HMM), the example you give is at Level 0. At this level, you are absolutely correct about the problems with this approach. It's a lot of work and developers are probably going to ignore it and hard-code things anyway. However, with a generic hypermedia enabled media type, not only does all that extra work go away, it actually reduces the work for developers.

Let's take a step back for a moment and consider how the web works. There are three main components: the web server, the web browser, and the driver (usually a human user). The web server provides HTML, which the web browser executes to present a graphical user interface, which the driver can use to follow links and fill out forms. The browser uses the HTML to completely abstract from the driver all the details about how to present the form and how to send it over HTTP.

In the API world, this concept of the generic browser that abstracts away the media type and HTTP details hasn't taken hold yet. The only one I know about that is both active and high quality is [Ketting](https://github.com/badgateway/ketting). Using a browser like Ketting, removes all of that extra work the developer would have to put into making use of all that hypermedia. A hypermedia browser is like an SDK that API vendors often provide except that it works for any API. In theory, you can link from one API to another completely unrelated API. APIs would no longer be islands, they would become a web.

The thing that makes hypermedia browsers possible are general purpose hypermedia enabled media types. HTML is of course the most successful and famous example, but there are JSON based media types as well. Some of the more widely used examples are [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) and [Siren](https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren).

The higher level a media type is on the [Hypermedia Maturity Model](https://8thlight.com/blog/jason-desrosiers/2018/05/30/the-hypermedia-maturity-model.html), the more that a generic browser can do to abstract way the media-type, URIs, and HTTP details. Here's a brief explanation. Checkout the blog post linked above for more details and examples.

**Level 0**: At this level, hypermedia is encoded in an ad-hoc way. A browser can't do much with this because every API might encode things a little different. At best a browser can use heuristics or AI to guess that something is a link or a form and treat it as such, but generally HMM Level 0 media-types are intended for developers to read an interpret. This leads to many of the challenges you identified your question. Examples: JSON and XML.

**Level 1**: At this level, links are a first class feature. The media type has a well defined way to represent a link. A browser knows unambiguously what is to be interpreted as a link and can provide an interface to follow that link without the user needing to be concerned about URI or HTTP. This is sufficient for read-only APIs, but if we need the user to provide input, we don't have a way to represent a form-like hypermedia control. It's up to a human to read the documentation or an ad-hoc form representation to know how to submit data. Examples: [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html), [RESTful JSON](https://restfuljson.org/).

**Level 2**: At this level, forms (or form-like controls) are a first class feature. A media type has a well defined way of representing a form-like hypermedia control. A browser can use this media type to do things like build an HTML Form, validate user input, encode user input into an acceptable media type, and make an HTTP request using the appropriate HTTP method. Let's say you want to change your API to support PATCH and you prefer that application start using it over PUT. If you are using a HMM Level 2 media type, you can change method in the representation and any application that uses a hypermedia browser that knows how to construct a PATCH request will start sending PATCHs instead of PUTs without any developer intervention. Without a HMM Level 2 media type, you're stuck with those PUTs until you can get all the applications that use your API to update their code. Examples: HTML, [HAL-Forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/), [Siren](https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren), [JSON Hyper-Schema](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-hypermedia.html), [Uber](https://rawgit.com/uber-hypermedia/specification/master/uber-hypermedia.html), [Mason](https://github.com/JornWildt/Mason), [Collection+JSON](https://github.com/collection-json/spec).

**Level 3**: At this level, in addition to hypermedia controls, data are also self-describing. Remember those three main components I mentioned? The last one, "driver", is the major difference between using hypermedia on the web and using hypermedia in an API. On the web, the driver is a human (excluding crawlers for simplicity), but with an API, the driver is an application. Humans can interpret the meaning of what they are presented with and deal with changes. Applications may act on heuristics or even AI, but usually they are following a fixed routine. If something changes about the data that the application didn't expect, the application breaks. At this level, we apply semantics to the data using something like [JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/). This allows us to construct drivers that are better at dealing with change and can even make decisions without human intervention. Examples: [Hydra](http://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/core/).

I think the only downside to choosing to use hypermedia in your API is that there aren't production-ready HMM Level 2 hypermedia browsers available in most languages. But, the good news is that one implementation will cover any API that uses a media type it supports. [Ketting](https://github.com/badgateway/ketting) will work for any API and application that is written in JavaScript. It would only take a few more similar implementations to cover all the major languages and choosing to use hypermedia would be an easy choice.

The other reason to choose hypermedia is that it helps with the API design process. I personally use [JSON Hyper-Schema](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-hypermedia.html) to rapid-prototype APIs and use a generic web client to click through links and forms to get a feel for API workflows. Even if no one else uses the schemas, for me, it's worth having even if just for the design phase.